# Configuring parameters for NUnit tests in TeamCity

Tags: .net, nunit, teamcity

Is there a way to configure parameters from the TeamCity UI, that can be accessed from .Net code during the NUnit test run?

Right now I know that it's possible to set an environmental variable in TC and then use it in the unit tests.

I would like to be able to quickly copy build configuration settings in teamcity, configure the tests differently and then run the build.

Thanks
AD

Comment: After a brief investigation I found out that having the teamCity build template having all environmental variables handled by my tests pre-defined is a pretty good choice. 

When I create a new build out of this template, all the settings are there on teamcity website.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @vikram, this is a good option. I will suggest another one. You may reference [FluentTc](https://github.com/QualiSystems/FluentTc) library, which allows programmatic access to TeamCity parameters.

`var buildId = new LocalTc().GetBuildParameter("build.id");`

The package is available on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentTc)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this.. may be..

- Create a config file that is read by your .net code before executing the test
- Update the contents of the config file from TC (using parameters) before any build steps are executed using the file content replace build feature.
- Run the build from TC with default parameters (run custom build if you would like to change any specific parameter instead of default)